# WeekNumber in WinRT

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

i wrote a program in VS 2012 for windows phone using silverlight, now i am trying to import my program to VS 2015 Universal app. In my program i need to get the week number of given date, for his i wrote followin function

```
public int WeekNumber(DateTime date)
{
   GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.Localized);
   return cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

But in winrt, there is no GregorianCalendar, i also try to create calender this way:

```
Windows.Globalization.Calendar cal = new Windows.Globalization.Calendar();
```

and then try to get weekofyear, but there is no such method.

Any idea how to get weeknumber of given date in winRT.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure if there's anything built in, but you could always implement the algorithm yourself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculating_the_week_number_of_a_given_date

Comment: Are you sure that's the week number rule you want to follow anyway? I only ask because there are lots of different options, and they're easy to get wrong.

Comment: You are writing in C#, you don't *have* to use the WinRT api.  You still have the .NET framework to help you out, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is readily available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that, when using `Windows.Globalization.Calendar`, you don't have `GetWeekOfYear` method, but if you use `System.Globalization.Calendar`, then you get the `GetWeekOfYear` method working. Based on this, below code working as needed.

```
public int WeekNumber(DateTime date)
{          
    DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    System.Globalization.Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
    return cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```